# Generalized Fresnel Integration: $\int_{0}^ {\infty } \sin(x^n) dx $ and $\int_{0}^ {\infty } \cos(x^n) dx $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function

I calculated generalized (w.r.t. the degree) Fresnel integrals 
 $\int_{0}^ {\infty } \sin(x^n) dx $  and 
 $\int_{0}^ {\infty } \cos(x^n) dx $
by contour integration.
And then I got 
 $$\int_{0}^ {\infty } \sin(x^n) dx =
 \frac{1}{2i}(i^{1/n} - i^{-1/n})
  \frac{1}{n}\Gamma\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), \\
 \int_{0}^ {\infty } \cos(x^n) dx =
 \frac{1}{2}(i^{1/n} + i^{-1/n})
  \frac{1}{n}\Gamma\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
Are these formulas correct? Can anyone please check their validity?

Comment: This is pretty illegible. Please use MathJax formatting. If you don’t know how, see the help documentation or click “edit” on any question to view it’s formatting.

Comment: I converted your formulas to MathJax and took the liberty to make some changes to the text. Feel free to revert the text changes if you don't like them. Your results are correct. The formulas can be simplified to $\sin(\pi/(2 n)) \Gamma(1 + 1/n)$ and $\cos(\pi/(2 n)) \Gamma(1 + 1/n)$.

Comment: Thanks, Maxim. Btw, how can it be simplified?

Comment: @JosephSchauder For the gamma function, we have $n \Gamma(n) = \Gamma(n + 1)$. For $i^{1/n}$, we're using the principal branch of the power function, that is, $(i^{1/n} + i^{-1/n})/2 = (e^{i \pi/(2 n)} + e^{-i \pi/(2 n)})/2$, which is the exponential form of the cosine.

Comment: I see. Thank you, Maxim!